# Como imprimir os valores matemáticos um abaixo do outro?

Tags: javascript

necessito retornar na tela os três valores em abaixo do outro e não um do lado do outro. Procurei bastante, mas não encontrei quebra de valores como assunto na documentação do javascript.
Segue Código abaixo:

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
    // Write your code here
    let len = arr.length;
    let positiveCount = 0;
    let negativoCount = 0;
    let zeroCount = 0;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > 0) {
            positiveCount++; 
        }
        else if (arr[i] < 0) {
            negativoCount++;
        }
        else if (arr[i] == 0) {
            zeroCount++;
        }
    }
    return console.log ((positiveCount / arr.length).toFixed(6), (negativoCount / arr.length).toFixed(6), (zeroCount / arr.length).toFixed(6));

}
```

Podem me ensinar a fazer a formatação desses valores?

Comment: Aqui no Stack Overflow se diz obrigado votando nas publicações. Veja: [Como dizer obrigado em respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas). Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Veja: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/137387)

Answer (score 3):

Uma possibilidade é o uso de [substituição de string](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Console) que segue essa tabela:

| String de substituição | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| %o | Emite um objeto JavaScript. |
| %d ou %i | Emite uma numero inteiro. Exemplo: `console.log("Foo %.2d", 1.1)`, o número será gerado como dois algarismos significativos com um 0 à esquerda:`Foo 01` |
| %s | Emite uma string. |
| %f | Emite um número de ponto flutuante. Exemplo: `console.log("Foo %.2f", 1.1)`, a saída do número com 2 casas decimais:`Foo 1.10` |

Cada um destes puxam o próximo argumento na lista de parâmetros após a string fornecida inicialmente.

No seu exemplo:

```js
function plusMinus(arr) {
  // Write your code here
  let len = arr.length;
  let positiveCount = 0;
  let negativoCount = 0;
  let zeroCount = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
      positiveCount++;
    } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
      negativoCount++;
    } else if (arr[i] == 0) {
      zeroCount++;
    }
  }
  return console.log(
      "%s\n%s\n%s\n", 
      (positiveCount / arr.length).toFixed(6),
      (negativoCount / arr.length).toFixed(6), 
      (zeroCount / arr.length).toFixed(6)
  );

}
plusMinus([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações, e por ensinar como fazer, eu realmente estava errando apenas em um pequeno trecho de sintaxe. Grato à todos!

Answer (score 1):

Levando em consideração que os valores só serão utilizados para serem apresentados no console, você pode inserir uma quebra de linha, dessa forma:

```js
function plusMinus(arr) {
    // Write your code here
    let len = arr.length;
    let positiveCount = 0;
    let negativoCount = 0;
    let zeroCount = 0;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > 0) {
            positiveCount++; 
        }
        else if (arr[i] < 0) {
            negativoCount++;
        }
        else if (arr[i] == 0) {
            zeroCount++;
        }
    }
    return console.log ((positiveCount / arr.length).toFixed(6), "\n"+ (negativoCount / arr.length).toFixed(6), "\n"+ (zeroCount / arr.length).toFixed(6));

}
plusMinus([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações, e por ensinar como fazer, eu realmente estava errando apenas em um pequeno trecho de sintaxe. Grato à todos!